# How rare are zombie villagers?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to find a zombie villager, but can someone tell me how rare they are, and what difficulty are they most common in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zombies have a 5% chance of naturally spawning as zombie villagers. This means that roughly every 1 in 20 zombies you find will be a zombie villager, making them "rare", but you should be able to find at least one every night while exploring.

One important thing to note is that in desert biomes, zombies will have an 80% chance of spawning as husks, which **CANNOT** turn into zombie villagers. This will make finding them in the desert 5 times harder.

If you are hunting for Zombie villagers, I suggest you find a populated village and stay until a [zombie siege](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_siege) occurs. On Hard difficulty, villagers who are killed by Zombies have a 100% chance of becoming a zombie villager. This decreases to 50% on Normal, and 0% on Easy.

---

Notes:

- Each igloo **with a basement** is guaranteed a zombie villager and a normal villager.
- Zombie villagers also have a 5% chance of spawning as baby form.

For more info check out the wiki pages for this: [Zombie#Spawning](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie#Spawning) and [Zombie Villager#Spawning](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_Villager#Spawning)

Comment: got any source or explanation on zombie villagers being more common in hard mode? I can't see difficulty mentioned anywhere else related to zombie villager spawning...

(I'm not talking about villagers turning into zombie villagers after being attacked)

Comment: @Flaming_Dorito i think you are correct, i was talking about how they can spawn when killed by a zombie, but reading it now, it does sound like i was talking about raw spawn rates (which do not increase from difficulty). gonna fix it asap

Comment: Ah that makes sense. thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

Zombie Villagers spawn when a Zombie kills a Villager.

In Easy there is a 0% chance after a kill

In Normal there is a 50% chance after a kill

In Hard and Hardcore there is a 100% chance after a kill.

They also have a 5% chance to spawn naturally.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Minecraft Wiki:](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_Villager)

> Zombies that are not husks have a 5% chance of naturally spawning as zombie villagers.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Not rly it just tells me their chance not what biome they're more common in

Answer (score 0):

According to the Minecraft wiki, zombie villagers have a 5 in 495 chance of spawning as a zombie villager when a hostile mob spawns in all biomes except deserts. There is a 95 in 495 chance of spawning a zombie in all biomes except deserts. This makes it a 1 in 19 chance a zombie will spawn as a zombie villager, as opposed to 1 in 20.

Answer (score -1):

Zombies have a 5% chance to spawn as a Zombie Villager and a 5% to spawn as a Baby Zombie. Baby Zombies have an additional 5% of spawning as a Chicken Jocky. This also applies to spawn eggs.